# Sagepay - making the billing address visible in VPS form

Tags: opayo

The billing address being sent by our system used to be visible when the system reached the VPS Form - so that it can be adjusted by the user at the time of entering their card details.

It is no longer visible since Sagepay updated their UI a few weeks ago.
This is leading to a lot of payments being declined which would never have been declined in the past.
How can I force it to remain visible?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the template back to Default in My Sage Pay. This will give you the old page, which isn't so great (OK, it's horrible) on a mobile device.